# How to make error pop-up appear using keyboard in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

When using IntelliJ IDEA and writing code, and when code you wrote has an error, the only way I know to make IDEA show you the error details is to hover the mouse cursor over the problem.

[image: Example error pop-up]

But that requires moving my hands from the keyboard to the mouse. Is there a hotkey that causes that pop-up with the error message to appear, or a way to configure such a hotkey?

Comment: I have a problem that this warning is shown with keyboard, but not with mouse. What setting should I change?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

On a Mac:

> <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

On Windows:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

On Linux:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>

You can check for anything else in Preferences -> Keymap

Comment: For Mac, I think that should be: Cmd + fn + F1

Comment: It is just Cmd+F1. You use fn+f1 because mac set function key as fn+function key by default. You can change it as normal function key in system settings.

Comment: since hovering the error line with the mouse does popup the notifcation automatically, why hovering the error line with cursor keys does not? btw. thank your for the shortcuts (which yet help a lot)

Answer (score 10):

On a Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>

On Windows: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>

These activate the menu item “View” → “Error Description” (which only exists when there is an error):

[image: the menu item “View” → “Error Description”]

You can configure and search for keyboard shortcuts in Preferences → Keymap:

[image: The “Error Description” keymap in Preferences → Keymap]

Answer (score 0):

In the year I write this, the shortcut is `Ctrl` + `1`.
( My OS is Arch Linux )