# IntelliJ View Error Description Not Showing on Hover

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Normally, when there is an error, I can hover over it and IntelliJ will show a little tooltip/popup describing the issue. However, recently this stopped working. I can still open the tooltip via the [menu/keyboard shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19681605/3345085), but how can I get it to show on a mouse hover again?

Example error tooltip:

[image: Example error tooltip]

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 (Community Edition).

Comment: Could you provide a code example?

Comment: @Duelist, it could be any error, such as referencing a non-existent variable. E.g. `val foo = nonexistent`

Answer (score 0):

`File` -> `Invalidate Caches...` -> `Invalidate and Restart`